# How to send JPEG image in multipart request using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, kotlin, httpurlconnection, multipart

I want to send image from gallery/camera to server. This image is compressed `Bitmap` and it is converted to `ByteArray`. Problem is that server returns error -> `file is not JPEG`. That means server did not recognized my content as JPEG. What could be wrong?

This is my API call for multipart request.

```
val data: ByteArray = convertBitmapToByteArray(bmp)
val con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            con.apply {
                requestMethod = method
                useCaches = false
                doOutput = true
                doInput = true
                addRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
                addRequestProperty("X-API-Key", apiType.apiKey)
                addRequestProperty("X-Session", session)
            }

            val request = DataOutputStream(con.outputStream)

            request.apply {
                writeBytes("$TWO_HYPHENS$BOUNDARY$CRLF")
                writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                        ATTACHMENT_NAME + "\";filename=\"" +
                        filename + "\"" + CRLF)
                writeBytes(CRLF)
                write(data)
                writeBytes(CRLF)
                writeBytes("$TWO_HYPHENS$BOUNDARY$TWO_HYPHENS$CRLF")
                flush()
                close()
            }

            val code = con.responseCode
            if (code/100 != 2) {
                if (code == 502){
                    //handle special error
                } else if (code >= 400) {
                    //handle errors
                }
                //handle errors
            }
            return getHttpResponseAsJson(con)
```

Converting Bitmap:

```
fun convertBitmapToByteArray(bmp: Bitmap): ByteArray{
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
    return stream.toByteArray()
}
```

Comment: I woul suggest to use Retrofit library it would make your life much easier

Comment: I dont know how to add API key and session token to Retrofit request.